# Chrome shows shortcut title instead of page title

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

If I start chrome from a shortcut the window title tab shows the name of the short cut instead of the title of the webpage. Windows opened from this window also has the title from the short cut instead of the website title.

Is there some setting to change to always show the webpage title.

Comment: It doesn't do this to me.

Comment: Open the shortcut in notepad and copy the contents of the shortcut file into your post please.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a shortcut on your desktop that links to a certain webpage. If that's the case, then Chrome is operating normally. If you open Chrome without clicking on that shortcut, then the words "New Tab - Google Chrome" should appear. Once you visit a webpage, your title bar is supposed to change to the webpage you are visiting.

Nothing wrong, just how Chrome works.